Precisely defining a Cevian
When I looked online, a Cevian is defined as "a line segment whose endpoints are a vertex of a triangle and any point on the triangle's opposite side".
Since any point includes the opposite side's endpoints, this could then include the triangle's other two sides too.
One source I found, but not others, mentioned that a Cevian splits a triangle into two smaller triangles, which would exclude the triangle's other two sides.
So I was planning on defining a Cevian as "a line segment whose endpoints are a vertex of a triangle and any point (except an endpoint) on the triangle's opposite side".  Is this variation okay, or is there a way to make it less ambiguous and more precise?

Rather than exclude the endpoints in your definition you could note afterwards that you are only interested in the non-trivial cases where the cevian does not coincide with an edge of the triangle.

Suggestions :
A Cevian is very general.
You can make it "Precise" by using "Interior Cevian" , "Exterior Cevian" & "Degenerate Cevian"
Cevian : Segment connecting a Vertex to the other side , with or without extending that side.
Interior Cevian : Cevian passing through some Internal Point of the triangle.
Exterior Cevian : Cevian passing through some External Point of the triangle , thoguh it requires extending the other side.
Degenerate Cevian : Cevian passing through coinciding with a side of the triangle.

We can see here the various types :
$AD_1$ is the "common/normal/regular" Internal Cevian which could be close to the Side Bisector or angle Bisector.
$AD_2$ is the External Cevian , which could be very close to the Altitude , which is also a Cevian.
$AD_3$ is also the External Cevian , though it is far from the Altitude.
$AB$ & $AC$ are the Degenerate Cevians , coinciding with a Side. A triangle might have the Altitude there itself.
You should start with what "Criteria" you require for your current analysis.
CASE X : Some theorems are valid when we take Internal Cevian.
Illustrative Example : Theorem 1 : Internal Cevian makes two triangles whose areas adds up to original triangle.
Here $\triangle ABC=\triangle ABD_2+\triangle AD_2C$ , adding up the areas : the theorem holds.
CASE Y : Some theorems are valid even when Degenerate Cevian occurs : "the two smaller triangles" degenerate into "the Original triangle $\triangle ABC$ with a thin line for the other triangle $\triangle ACC$ which will have Zero area".
Here $\triangle ABC=\triangle ABC+\triangle ACC=\triangle ABC+0$ , adding up the areas , including $0$ : the theorem holds.
[[ This is very much like $\sin 180 = 0$ where we let the triangle have $0$ length ]]
CASE Z : Some theorems are invalid when External Cevian occurs : Here it is not true that $\triangle ABC=\triangle ABD_2+\triangle AD_2C$
What we have here is a large triangle $\triangle AD_2C$ with some sort of "Negative" triangle $\triangle ABD_2$ which will have "Negative" area.
Illustrative Example : Theorem 2 : External Cevian makes two triangles whose areas difference is the original triangle.
Illustrative Example : Theorem 3 : All Cevians make two triangles whose areas add up to the original triangle , when we consider Signed Areas.
Here $\triangle ABC=\triangle ABD_2+\triangle AD_2C=-\triangle AD_2B+\triangle AD_2C$ , adding up the "Signed" areas , taking Counter-Clock-Wise=Positive while Clock-Wise=Negative : the theorem holds.
[[ This is very much like $\sin 270 = -1$ where we let the triangle have Negative length ]]
Summary :
We have to decide what scenarios we want to cover & use the "Suitable Definition" to cover that.
Suitable Interpretations will make certain theorems valid in all Cases. When that is true , we can make a more general theorem. When that is not true , we have to use the restricting terminology.
